# How Can I get actions published on facebook via API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

If I publish on my facebook profile an action like: eating pizza, or playing soccer, etc, How I can get these actions with graph api?

I read the Facebook docs but I found only the calls for get books reading, video watching and music listening...and for the other actions? is it possible? how?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It depends whether the apps use their own actions, or use the common ones. A lsiting of the common FB actions can be found at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph

Docs:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-actions/v2.1
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/creating-custom-stories#actiontypes
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-actions/v2.1#read

The last link describes how to query for custom actions. Either

```
/{user-id}/{namespace}:{action-type-name}
```

or

```
/{user-id}/{action-type}?app_id_filter={app-id}
```

can be used, but for both you'll need to know some app details.

Answer (score 0):

I am not referring to the actions created by my app, but I mean those actions already available in facebook. Look at the picture here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQEZ2.png